# Get Music Data in XML format

Tags: xml, database

for a practice in my school I need to build a database. In this I need to add some data, in my case of music titles, interprets or something like this.

Is there any known source which provides data like this in a structured xml format?

So that I have information like:

- Interpreter
- Title
- Length
- Country
- ...

So I don´t have to add the music file itself, but need information for a lot of objects without dummy data.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The following link should get you started to retrieve whatever you need: https://freemusicarchive.org/api. You can hit the API using something like PostMan https://www.getpostman.com/ to source the data from the API.